# Python Segmentation Fault - Not Observed when run in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I have developed python script(s) in Eclipse, and it(they) run(s) OK.

However, when i try to run it in standalone mode (from bash prompt), i am getting  Segmentation Fault.

I have already tried all usual suspects - changed several python versions, numpy versions and so on. I actually see this problem on the linux/ubuntu side, nothing of sorts in the windows side.

For example, when running one of the scripts in debug mode (`-q -X faulthandler`)
i see something like this:

```
'''
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007fc2240f4700 (most recent call first):
  File "/local/mnt/anaconda33/envs/radarlog2/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348 in __init__
  File "/local/mnt/anaconda33/envs/radarlog2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 39 in load_dll
  File "/local/mnt/anaconda33/envs/radarlog2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 92 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/local/mnt/anaconda33/envs/radarlog2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/coords.py", line 8 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/local/mnt/anaconda33/envs/radarlog2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 18 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/local/mnt/anaconda33/envs/radarlog2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "createVideo_v01.py", line 15 in <module>
'''
```

and corresponding line is simple import statement:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon as sPolygon
```

i am puzzled what is causing this behavior, and why i do not see this problem when running the same code through Eclipse IDE.

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: Check what version of python gets run from eclipse what is the version you run , try --version.

Comment: same versions, thanks for suggesting - this was the first thing i looked at